# Spider-Man and the death of Gwen Stacy

Tags: comics, spider-man, marvel

Given Peter Parker's incredible intellect, wouldn't Spider-Man be smart enough to know sling-shotting Gwen would break her neck?

Comment: Obviously not. She's died. He was a teenager, he was in an extreme circumstance, he made the best call he could given what he knew. It simply wasn't good enough. "Experience is what you get when you didn't get what you wanted."

Comment: He also didn't really have much choice of what else to do. If he let her fall she'd most likely die, he catches her with his web, she may survive. Also, it was a reaction thing, as fast as thought is, any time he spends thinking about what to do is less time to save her. So he reacts and it goes wrong.

Comment: Later on he learned from his faults and started saving people by pulling himself towards them in mid fall but atill don't believe he wasn't smart or experienced enough he had been in situation similar before and knowledge of physic and experimental science

Answer (score 8):

Spider-man is superhumanly strong and tough.  His body recovers from injuries very quickly, he can shake off blows from people who would turn a normal person into a fine red mist, and he can lift a truck.

He's also learned almost everything he knows about webslinging by instinct and experience.

Thus, his initial experience in webslinging (and recall, he was still a teen when Gwen died, not the experienced adult he later became) is with the effects upon his own body.

Suffice to say, he can take far more G-Forces and far more punishment than most humans.  Had he stopped himself from falling the way he stopped Gwen, he would have survived with little more than some residual bruising and soreness.  In fact, he'd stopped himself that way previously.

Time was critical - he had literally a split second to choose a course of action and act - he reacted on instinct.  His knowledge of physics of normal human bodies requires thought.

In short - he made the worst possible call for the best reasons.